# How to find the length of a line in a text file?

Tags: c, stdio

I'm begginer in programming and I can't figure how to find length of line in text file in C language. 
I have text file where are names and numbers, every name and number is on different line and when I need to print it in output I need to have name and number on same line. But in text file it has to be on different. How can I accomplish to that please?

example of text file:

```
Name Surname1
789456133
Name Surname2
135486661
Name Surname3
984651333
```

Now my output looks like this:

```
Name Surname1
, 789456133
Name Surname2
, 135486661
Name Surname3
, 984651333
```

using `printf("%s, %s", name, number)`;

And I need it like this:

```
Name Surname1, 789456133 
Name Surname2, 135486661
Name Surname3, 984651333
```

I know, that I somehow need to count length of name line + length of number line without /n

We also can't use fscanf.

Someone please help.  Thank you.

Comment: Please supply the code that you have tried

Comment: Can you include an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You can count two newline characters and then print a newline otherwise only print the characters and when you encounter odd newline print a space. This will merge two different lines into one.

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main() {
char line[1000];
int i;

printf("Enter the line: ");
scanf("%s", line);

for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; ++i);

printf("Length of line is %d", i);

return 0;
```

}

output:
Enter the line: hii hello

Length of line is 9

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of a string with `strlen` (eg: `strlen(str)`)

by doing `str[ strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';` you can get rid of the newline altogether (provided that the string ends with `'\n'`, check that!)

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `fscanf` here to read both `name` and `number` in a single call and then handle the `'\n'` left in your input buffer unread -- don't, that is a horribly fragile way to approach the read of sequential lines and `scanf` and `fscanf` are full of many pitfalls for the new C programmer. It is far better to read a line-at-a-time with a *line-oriented* input function such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`.

To use line oriented input, always declare a buffer of sufficient size to handle your anticipated max line of data (and then double, or quadruple the size for the buffer) For example, in your case, with a maximum anticipated line of 14-characters, a buffer size of `64` characters will do (don't skimp on buffer size). For example:

```
#define MAXC 64
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char name[MAXC], number[MAXC];  /* buffers to hold name name number */
    ..                              /* open/validate file is open here */
```

For your read loop, you can simply loop continually and read a line into `name` and a line into `number` validating that each succeeds, e.g.

```
    while (1) {         /* loop continually reading each line until EOF */
        if (!fgets (name, MAXC, fp))        /* read/validate name into name */
            break;
        name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;     /* trim trailing '\n' */
        if (!fgets (number, MAXC, fp))      /* read/validate number */
            break;
        number[strcspn (number, "\n")] = 0; /* trim trailing '\n' */
        ...
```

Now if you get to this point in your loop you have filled both `name` and `number` with the related strings, so just output your values separated by a comma, e.g.

```
        ...
        printf ("%s, %s\n", name, number);  /* output result */
    }
```

Close your file and you are done. Note the use of [`strcspn()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html) to trim the trailing `'\n'`. This is a very quick and reliable way to handle removing the `'\n'` by simply overwriting it with `'\0'` (equivalent to simply `0`).

If you incorporate the forgoing logic, your output would be as desired:

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in filename `dat/name_number.txt` passed as the first argument to your program, you would get:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_name_number dat/name_number.txt
Name Surname1, 789456133
Name Surname2, 135486661
Name Surname3, 984651333
```

Work though the logic, incorporate with the code you have, and let me know if you have further questions or get stuck. If you get stuck, post your complete code as an edit and *addition* to your question. Do not erase what you have already posted. (indent your code by 4-spaces so it formats correctly in your edited question)

Answer (score 0):

We also can't use fscanf, so I edited my question.

But I somehow managed it

I will write my code after few hours, now I have to go :D

Thank everyone for they answers